# Javascript DOM não reconhece as mudanças que fiz no HTML

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Estou estudando javascript e nesse momento estou tentando fazer uma simples pagina para finanças pessoais, mostrar o montante, adicionar novas transações e mostrar as transações, e onde está mostrado, eu posso alterar o excluir essa transação.

Estou utilizando o json-server para simular o banco de dados, pois nao aprendi db ainda.

O que estou fazendo no momento:
Eu tenho essa função para mostrar na pagina as transações e adiciono diversos elementos no HTML
:

```
//Function to render the transactions at the HTML
function renderTransactions(transactions) {
  //Create div to each transaction
  const transaction = document.createElement("div");
  transaction.classList.add(`transaction`);
  transaction.id = `transaction-${transactions?.id}`;
  //Create transaction reason
  const reason = document.createElement("h3");
  reason.classList.add("transaction-reason");
  reason.textContent = `${transactions?.id}-->${transactions?.reason}`;
  //Create transaction value
  const value = document.createElement("h3");
  value.classList.add("transaction-value");
  value.textContent = `R$: ${transactions?.value}`;
  //Create edit icon
  const edit = new Image(20, 20);
  edit.src = "./img/editar.png";
  edit.id = "edit-icon";
  //Create delete icon
  const delet = new Image(20, 20);
  delet.src = "./img/escluir.png";
  delet.id = "delet-icon";
  value.append(edit, delet);
  //Put all 2 at the div
  transaction.append(reason, value);
  //Put at the div transactions
  document.querySelector(".transactions").appendChild(transaction);
}
```

Da pra ver que eu adiciono um icone de edit e o outro delete e eles ficam assim na pagina:
[como fica os icones](https://i.stack.imgur.com/82uN5.png)

O que eu quero fazer agora é adcionar os eventos de click nessas imagens pra elas fazerem o que devem, alterar ou excluir a transação, entretanto, estou com problemas em pegar no DOM novamente essa imagem que eu adicionei o HTML com o ID dela, recebo apenas null:

```
//Delete function
const imgClick = document.getElementById("delet-icon");
imgClick.addEventListener("click", (ev) => {
  const div = ev.target;
  console.log(div);
});
```

[esse é o erro que recebo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BexGf.png) quando faz o DOM e o event

[imagem dos ids](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EbZph.png) que eu criei com o DOM e elas estão no HTML

Aqui ta o código completo:

```
    //Function to render the transactions at the HTML
function renderTransactions(transactions) {
  //Create div to each transaction
  const transaction = document.createElement("div");
  transaction.classList.add(`transaction`);
  transaction.id = `transaction-${transactions?.id}`;
  //Create transaction reason
  const reason = document.createElement("h3");
  reason.classList.add("transaction-reason");
  reason.textContent = `${transactions?.id}-->${transactions?.reason}`;
  //Create transaction value
  const value = document.createElement("h3");
  value.classList.add("transaction-value");
  value.textContent = `R$: ${transactions?.value}`;
  //Create edit icon
  const edit = new Image(20, 20);
  edit.src = "./img/editar.png";
  edit.id = "edit-icon";
  //Create delete icon
  const delet = new Image(20, 20);
  delet.src = "./img/escluir.png";
  delet.id = "delet-icon";
  value.append(edit, delet);
  //Put all 2 at the div
  transaction.append(reason, value);
  //Put at the div transactions
  document.querySelector(".transactions").appendChild(transaction);
}

//Async function to GET
async function fetchTransGET() {
  const transactions = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/transactions").then(
    (res) => res.json()
  );
  transactions.forEach(renderTransactions);
  transactions.forEach(valueUpdate);
}
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => fetchTransGET());

//async function to POST
form = document.querySelector("form");
form.addEventListener("submit", async (ev) => {
  ev.preventDefault();
  const transactionData = {
    reason: document.querySelector("#name").value,
    value: document.querySelector("#value").value,
  };
  if (transactionData.reason === "" || transactionData.value === "") {
  } else {
    const response = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/transactions", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(transactionData),
    });
    const postedTransaction = await response.json();
    form.reset();
    renderTransactions(postedTransaction);
    valueUpdate(postedTransaction);
  }
});

//Function to get and maintain the value updated
let totalValue = 0;
function valueUpdate(transaction) {
  const value = document.getElementById("amount");
  totalValue += parseFloat(transaction.value);
  value.textContent = `Amount:R$${totalValue}`;
}

//Delete function
const imgClick = document.getElementById("delet-icon");
imgClick.addEventListener("click", (ev) => {
  const div = ev.target;
  console.log(div);
});
```

Comment: Olá! Evite postar prints de código. Sempre prefira postar código no formato texto, devidamente formatado como código. Isso aumenta suas chances de obter a ajuda solicitada.

Comment: okok, modifiquei e coloquei os códigos onde dava.

Comment: Eu diria que o problema é de sincronia: logo após setar o eventListener para quando o DOM carrega, seu script continua rodando. Ele chega nas últimas linhas e tenta detectar a `imgClick` antes de rodar a função `renderTransactions` -- ou seja, quando não há nenhum elemento com id `delet-icon` no DOM (pois a referida função ainda não os inseriu).

Comment: A meu ver, a forma mais fácil de resolver é definir o listener para o clique logo depois de criar o botão, dentro da função `renderTransaction`. Por exemplo, abaixo de `delet.id = "delet-icon";`, você aproveita e coloca `delet.addEventListener("click", (ev) => { resto da função }`. E apaga essa função lá no final.

Comment: Mais um detalhe: é uma má prática repetir ids para elementos do DOM. Em tese, os ids devem ser únicos (é provável que o console do Chrome tenha avisado isso).

Comment: certo, irei tentar fazer e vejo o resultado, na questao dos ids como sou meio novo e nao conheço muito de boas praticas, eu criei os ids da forma que ficasse transaçao-1,transação-2

Comment: é isso mesmo resolveu meu problema, muito obrigado pela ajuda